# Can cron be reconfigured to run a script instead of sending email?

Tags: cron

I'm thinking of configuring cron to sending message to my Synapse Matrix instance instead of sending email, is it possible? Is it possible to configure cron to do something else, instead of sending email?

I guess one way would be to symlink /usr/bin/mail to something else, but maybe there is something better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cron emails the output of your commands by default. If you want something else, you can either discard the output `> /dev/null` or redirect to some other command/tool:

```
your_cron_job_command | some_other_tool
```

Comment: Yes so what I would like is to modify this default behavior, maybe there is a cron that does this already?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I discovered that cron actually has -m parameter, just looks like Debian's cron does not have it, or the man page is missing this parameter.

The -m parameter is documented here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron